# Create an application and attach it on right-click on a file

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2012

I want to make an application in C# VS12 preferably, and I want to attach it on right click menu passing the filepath as an argument, it would be great if I could do that on multiple selection too. How do I make that happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the installer of your application you need to add a file extension association. (for development you can test that by registering the extension manually: right click, open with...). the file name that was clicked will be passed to your app as a command line argument (those are the args[] in the main method of you app).

multiple selection is a bit trickier but certainly doable. when your app starts you need to check if you have an instance of the app already running (using a mutex for example) and send a message to that instance with the file name you received.

Comment: so on multiple selection it opens a new instance of the application for every filepath instead of passing the filepaths into args[]?

Comment: yes, the os will start your app for each file the user selects

Answer (score 0):

If you have not worked with context menu handling, you should take a look at [this tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776881%28VS.85%29.aspx).

For the file path handling, you could take a look at [this image editing example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15171/Simple-shell-context-menu).